# Decoding Morse Code with strtok in binary tree - garbage output

Tags: c++, string, binary-tree, strtok, morse-code

I was able to encode English to Morse Code but I am having trouble doing the reverse operation. Here's what I have so far:

In the main():

```
cout << "Enter your Morse code, separated by /, ended by *: ";
cin.getline(morseCode, 100, '*');
char* token = strtok(morseCode, "/");
while(token != NULL)
{
    cout << endl << "Decoding: " << token << endl;
    string newCode = token;
    t.Decode(newCode);
    token = strtok(NULL, "/");
}
```

Decode function:

```
void Decode(string x)
{
    Node* r = SearchAndReturnString(root, x);
    if(r->code == x) cout << r->letter;
    else cout << r->code << " with x being " << x << endl; cout << "Error.";
}
```

My output is a bunch of random garbage data then the program crashes. I know it has something to do with the `SearchAndReturnString` function but I can't figure out what else to do with it.

---

### Edit:

Node structure:

```
struct Node
{
    string letter;
    string code;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
```

SearchAndReturn function:

```
Node* SearchAndReturnString(Node *r, string x)
{
    if(r != NULL)
    {
        if(r->code == x) {cout << r->code << " matches " << x << endl; return r;}
        else if(r->code > x) {SearchAndReturnString(r->left, x);}
        else {SearchAndReturnString(r->right, x);}
    }
    else return NULL;
}
```

Here's the entire code as requested:

Header: http://pastebin.com/QyaakvMK

Main: http://pastebin.com/NcseqrbX

Comment: `morseCodeNew` points to a single char. If the token you read is longer than 1 character, you're overrunning your buffer when you `strcpy()` it.

Comment: I changed it to an array. It still has the same output.

Comment: Why the copy? `morseCodeNew` already points to a null-terminated string. You can already do `cout << token << endl`.

Comment: You might also want to show the definition of `Node` and the algorithm for `SearchAndReturn`.

Comment: Removing the copy didn't solve it either. Only reason I did it was because I was researching online how to decode Morse code, and people suggested that you copy to a new variable.

Comment: Will be easier with a compilable version of the code, or at least something we can run since you are talking about incorrect behavior and a crash at runtime.  Your usage of strtok is correct so I doubt thats the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem would seem to be that while you're passing a `std::string` to `tree.Decode`, it then calls `SearchAndReturn` with the same variable as though it were a single `char`.  Your question fails to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's hard to know which is correct, but at least one is not.

Comment: I have two SearchAndReturn functions and I posted the wrong one. Sorry for the confusion but it's fixed in the post now. I was able to debug a bit further today and I can conclude that it has to do with the SearchAndReturn function returning a pointer to nothing. But I cannot figure out why it does this.